# JavaScript to check which one of the given numbers differs from other

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am stuck on a problem. I want to print the index of an array which differs from other elements of that array in evenness. To be more specific the input would be like 5 even numbers and 1 odd number. So print the position(index+1) of odd number.

My code

```js
function Test(numbers){

    var e = 0;    //number of even numbers
    var o = 0;    //number of odd numbers

    console.log(numbers.length);

  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  
    if(numbers[i] % 2 == 0){
      e++;
      var pose = i;            //index of even no
   }
    else{
   o++
      var poso = i;    //index of odd number
 }
    
   }

   if(e==1){                 //only one even number
     console.log(pose+1);     
   }
   else if(o==1){            //only one odd number
     console.log(poso+1);
   }
   else{
     console.log("no number differs");   
   }
}


Test("2 4 7 8 6");
```

Expected output = '3';

The console prints :

> "no number differs".

I have debugged and I found the problem. The `console.log(numbers.length)`; is printing 9. That is it is including blank spaces as well. Same if we put comma ',' in between the numbers. Also if there is a two digit number it treats them as 2 separate elements.

Now I know that i can add code at the beginning to check if i=1,3,5... to break the loop but I would like to know if there is a better solution. Also if the solution is passing array in different format I would like to know how can we correct the code if we want to pass as above.

Comment: Sorry the console prints 5. But it is still wrong.

Comment: *"I want to print the index of an array"* - Well then why don't you actually pass an **array** of numbers to the function: `Test([2, 4, 7, 8, 6])`? Currently you're passing a string, not an array. Or in the first line of your function convert the string of numbers to an array with `numbers = numbers.split(/\s+/);`.

Comment: Thanks, all!  I feel so dumb.... @nnnnnn cheers for that split method as well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an array as an argument like below.

```js
function Test(numbers){

    var e = 0;    //number of even numbers
    var o = 0;    //number of odd numbers

    console.log(numbers.length);

  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  
    if(numbers[i] % 2 == 0){
      e++;
      var pose = i;            //index of even no
   }
    else{
   o++
      var poso = i;    //index of odd number
 }
    
   }

   if(e==1){                 //only one even number
     console.log(pose+1);     
   }
   else if(o==1){            //only one odd number
     console.log(poso+1);
   }
   else{
     console.log("no number differs");   
   }
}


var x = [2,4,7,8,6];
Test(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Program is absolutely fine.
I guess the problem is with how you are passing data to your function Test.

You are passing a string instead of array.
it should be like:

**Test([2,4,7,8,6]);**

Also If you want to pass it as string just make sure you split the String with ',' comma and make an array of the numbers and then feed it to your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are passing the argument as a string, but I guess you may need to pass an array. 
If it is so then you can look into array#forEach method

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
function Test(numbers) {
  // looping through the array
  numbers.forEach(function(item, index) {
    //checking if it is odd or even
    if (item % 2 == 0) {
      console.log("current number is Even & its index is " + index);
    } else {
      //updating index
      var modIndex = index+1;
      console.log("current number is Odd & its modified index is " + modIndex);
    }


  })
}

var num = ['2','4','7','8','6']

Test(num);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0e6upqj7/2/)